# Multiple words search and calculation algorithm (Angular/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, algorithm

I'm loading json file from database with two fields words and grade. Each word is graded for example true has 1 while lie has -1. Then i take input from text filed and i need to grade it based on grades from JSON file and then calculate score by summarizing the grades, but i just can't seem to find the way to do that. Words that are not in file are not being calculated.

I tried string.search match but it's to complicated and in the end i couldn't get result the way i wanted. I tried array searches same thing. I searched for on line solution, but no one has done anything similar so i can't copy it.

**JSON**

```
[
  {"word":"true","grade":1},
  {"word":"hate","grade":-1},
  {"word":"dog","grade":0.8},
  {"word":"cat","grade":-0.8}      
]
```

**String**

***"Dogs are wonderful but i prefer cats, cats, i can not lie although dog is a true friend".***

Comment: So could u show how far have your tried? The logic is not that complicated. i don't think it is necessary to have an **algorithm** if complexity is not a big problem.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Check http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @IvanSivak is correct. It should be wrapped with `[]` and not `{}`.

Comment: Ye i typed it wrong i have reworked it now. But anyway works fine in program i output data with no problems from it. @jsonlint.com

Comment: @MMhunter I've deleted all my solutions because none of them work, maybe it's not complicated, but for me it is, i can't seem to find the way. 
When you speak about it, it seem straight forward but when you try to search the string and manipulate, I get lost :)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is turn your JSON data into a map which can easily be searched - key would be the word, and value the grade:

```js
var json = [
  {"word":"true","grade":1},
  {"word":"hate","grade":-1},
  {"word":"dog","grade":0.8},
  {"word":"cat","grade":-0.8}      
  ];

var map = json.reduce(function(p,c){
    p.set(c.word.toLowerCase(),c.grade);
  return p;
}, new Map());

console.log(...map);
```

Then, its just a case of splitting your string, whilst also calculating the total score - again `reduce` can be used

```js
var json = [
      {"word":"true","grade":1},
      {"word":"hate","grade":-1},
      {"word":"dog","grade":0.8},
      {"word":"cat","grade":-0.8}      
      ];

    var map = json.reduce(function(p,c){
        p.set(c.word.toLowerCase(),c.grade);
      return p;
    }, new Map());

var input = "Dogs are wonderful but i prefer cats cats i can not lie although dog is a true friend";

var score = input.split(' ').reduce(function(p,c){
    var wordScore = map.get(c.toLowerCase()) || 0;
    return p + wordScore;
},0);

console.log(score);
```

Note that I have manually removed punctuation in the above input - I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Also note that `"cats" != "cat"` so some of your words wont be found!

Comment: You are genius, this is perfect, i never used maps and i don't know how to use them so that is the second exercise i will have to do, see how it works and removing punctuation should be my job! Thanks a lot...really, I've busted my head with these for days now.

Comment: If i want cats to be found what do i need to add? Just curious

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginer - you could use a [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) or you could change to using a regex pattern similar to the other answer. It all depends how you want your score matches to work! You'll notice I already had to deal with case sensitivity by using `toLowerCase()` on both the word score map and the input processing.

Comment: The problem with both the above suggestions is that if you look for words starting `cat` do you want the name `catherine` to be a match? probably not! same for regex, if you look for any word *containing* `cat` do you want a hit from the word `scathing`? again, probably not. This gets complex quickly. Decide your rules, code appropriately.

Comment: Great answers, i was going to think that maybe even lie, and lie's shouldn't be same grade lies are multiple worse. Anyway your solution was perfect. Where can i find and exercise this things?

Comment: `Where can i find and exercise this things?` <- I dont understand this question

Comment: For example i heaven t even knew that JavaScript has Map object, where did you learn all this? :D

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript (and, experience!)

Comment: You are true friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's first think of the algorithm. Two options:

1. Search and count the input string as many times as number of words in your JSON, or
2. Check each word in your input string against the JSON contents.

Since the JSON length is known and (I presume) shorter than the possible input string, I would tend to prefer option 2.

Now, after selecting option 2, you need to split the input string into words and create an array containing one word each entry of the array.

You can achieve this using the `mystring.split(" ")` method. This, of course, does not take into account punctuations, but you can handle this using the same method.

Now, you can add to each entry in your JSON a field to count the number of appearances of each entry in the JSON within the string.

Finally, you sum the product of the counters and the grade.

Comment: Punctuation can be removed prior to  calculation so it will be easier. Seems fine idea and i was thinking that aloud myself but i don't know how to do it in code :(

Comment: Well, I don't have a **ready** example and cannot write the code and test it, but can give you some guidelines. First, replace all punctuations with blanks. Second, replace all double-blanks with a single one. Third, split the string like `var words_array = instring.split(" ");`. Forth, create two loops, the outer over the length of the array `words_array` from `0` to `words_arrray.length`, while the inner loop goes from `0` to `known_words.length`. within the inner loop, compare the entries and add one to the counter when match.

Comment: One clarification: Each cycle of the outer loop you need to add an element to the JSON of the known words, something like: `known_words[k].count = 0` where `k` is the index of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log((function(rules, str) {
  var sum = 0;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(rules, function(rule) {
    var match = str.match(rule.regexp);
    
    match && (sum += str.match(rule.regexp).length * rule.grade);
    console.log([rule.regexp, match&&match.length, rule.grade, match&&match.length * rule.grade, sum]);
  });
  return sum;
})([{
  "regexp": /true/g,
  "grade": 1
}, {
  "regexp": /hate/g,
  "grade": -1
}, {
  "regexp": /dog/g,
  "grade": 0.8
}, {
  "regexp": /cat/g,
  "grade": -0.8
}], "Dogs are wonderful but i prefer cats, cats, i can not lie although dog is a true friend"));
```

i use regexp rather than string, u can use string and convert to regex at run time, hope this would help